# Is there a way to change the cursor when using the brush tool in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools

I can't stand how the cursor for the brush tool is an actual brush in Illustrator. It makes it really difficult to see where I am going with the brush. Is there a way to change it so that the cursor is a circle that shows you exactly where you're about to brush?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, open **Edit → Preferences → General** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)

And turn on "Use Precise Cursors"
[image: Use Precise Cursors]
This will change your tool tip to cross-hairs:

[image: crosshair tooltip]
[**GIF**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zrUq.gif)

<sub>(This applies for all of the tools.)</sub>

---

Also, to quickly toggle it on/off just hit <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>